# Confused about which Apache SVN package to use with windows

Tags: java, svn, jakarta-ee, version-control

i want to make svn repo on a windows machine, but when i tried to download the Apache SVN
i found lots of packages here:

http://subversion.apache.org/packages.html#windows

but i am confused which package to use
what do you guys suggest ?

Comment: do you want to make a local repo? or a shared repo over http(s)?

Comment: what is the difference ?

Comment: If you have a local repo, you can just install the command line version or tortoise SVN, but it's not ideal to share it over the internet and it's has some drawbacks to share with other computer over a network. But if you want more people to access it, you'll need a server, in which case you can pick one of the servers that @Ayusman mentioned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can pay for it, go for visual SVN server (the basic edition is free though)

if you want a free one, take silkSVN or win32svn.

I used win32svn and it works like a charm. I had set up project SVN server on a windows 2003 server.

This link helped me:

http://www.inetsolution.com/turnleft/post/How-to-Setup-Subversion-2b-Apache-2b-WebSVN-on-Windows.aspx

Comment: is there an easy way with GUI to do that, because there are lots of steps ?

Comment: yes, visual SVN can help. Try it out, it's one of the simplest. It also installs apache service I guess.

Answer (score 2):

- WANdisco Windows Subversion Client 1.6.17 - if you want only local or svn:// served repo and can live with console command
- VisualSVN Server - if you want Apache-served repos with easy installer and GUI-management in Server Management Console - free Standard Edition is good if you haven't to manage a lot of remote VisualSVN servers